# UISegmentController and UIViews

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I would like to know how to correctly operate with two views by `UISegmentController`.

Now I have two `UIViews` and `UISegmentController` and procedure **changeView**:

```
- (void)changeView:(NSInteger)index {
switch (index) {
    case 0:
        self.recipeInfoView.alpha = 1;
        self.recipeInfoView2.alpha = 0;
        break;
    case 1:
        self.recipeInfoView.alpha = 0;
        self.recipeInfoView2.alpha = 1;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

This code works, but each view have the same position and size and very uncomfortable to work with it. 
I'm using storyboards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First write following code For create `UISegmentedControl` and give color of your `UIView`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
       
   //Make hide of your UIView 
       self.recipeInfoView.hide = YES;
       self.recipeInfoView2.hide = YES;

  //Give color of your UIView
       self.recipeInfoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
       self.recipeInfoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

  //Create UISegmentedControl Controller 
    NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"FirstView", @"SecondView", nil];
    self.segmentedControl= [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
    self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(35, 100, 250, 33);
    self.segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    self.segmentedControl.momentary=NO;
    self.segmentedControl.tintColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];

    [self.segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    
    [self.view addSubview:self.segmentedControl];
   
}
```

// segmentAction Methods

```
- (IBAction)segmentAction:(id)sender
{
    if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 0)
    {
       if(self.recipeInfoView.isHidden == YES)
          self.recipeInfoView.Hidden == NO;
      else
          self.recipeInfoView.Hidden == NO;

      if(self.recipeInfoView2.isHidden == YES)
           self.recipeInfoView2.Hidden == YES;
      else
           self.recipeInfoView2.Hidden == YES;

   }
   else if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 1)
   {
       if(self.recipeInfoView2.isHidden == YES)
           self.recipeInfoView2.Hidden == NO;
       else
           self.recipeInfoView2.Hidden == NO;

       if(self.recipeInfoView.isHidden == YES)
            self.recipeInfoView.Hidden == YES;
       else
           self.recipeInfoView.Hidden == YES; 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set view property hidden = YES or NO instead of setting alpha for view